# JavaScript Remove Object From Array & Return It

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Using JavaScript how can I remove an object from an array and return that object? For example, change this:

```
[{first:"John", last:"Smith"}]
```

...to this:

```
{first:"John", last:"Smith"}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VqBCsXGuMM54MwHIKW3c?p=preview

Comment: You will have to show a little more context of the variable construction for a complete answer.  Is this array assigned to a variable by itself or part of some other object?

Comment: @jfriend00 It's assigned to a variable by itself - Plunker added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). It will remove some items from the array and return them.

```
var data = [{first:"John", last:"Smith"}];
var extract = data.splice(0, 1);
console.log(extract, data); // will print: {first..., last...}, []
```

Note that splice does return an array itself, so you'll have to take the appropriate elements from that.

If you only have a single element, you can `splice`, `pop`, or simply take the element by index and then truncate the array.

Comment: `.splice` is returning an array with an object (not just an object). Am I missing something? Compare to `myObject`: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pg3rLv2Lspj118i34EBa?p=preview

Comment: @Ryan I mentioned that in the answer. `splice` will remove the elements from the original array and return a new array, which you have to take the element from normally (`data.splice(0, 1)[0]` or the like). It does the important step of removing, especially since it can remove element(s) from the middle of another array efficiently.

Comment: So that's my question, how can I return just an object (not an array with an object)? I'm getting `undefined` when I try `.pop()`: http://plnkr.co/edit/Pg3rLv2Lspj118i34EBa?p=preview

Comment: You can use `data.splice(0, 1).pop()` or `data.splice(0, 1)[0]` or any number of other methods. There is no built-in method (that I know of) to splice a single element out of an array and return it as an object, probably because that behavior wouldn't make sense for multiple elements.

Comment: `data.splice(0, 1).pop();` and `data.splice(0, 1)[0]` both return `undefined` http://plnkr.co/edit/Pg3rLv2Lspj118i34EBa?p=preview

Comment: @Ryan that's because `splice` mutates the original array and you're running it multiple times. After the first `splice`, there's *nothing left* in `data` to get in the next call.

Comment: If this helps others - the answer (from ssube) is: http://plnkr.co/edit/O8X58uzN573RkQXbCTMw?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method.
It will always remove the last element from array and handle it to you;

Example:

```
var myArray = [{first:"John", last:"Smith"}]
var myObject = myArray.pop()
```

Now your `myObject` value will be `{first:"John", last:"Smith"}` and your `myArray` will be empty

If you had more than one items:

```
var myArray = [{first:"John", last:"Smith"}, {first:"Test", last:"Now"}]
var myObject = myArray.pop()
```

What happens here is that your myArray will have just the first value and the myObject will have the last one `{first:"Test", last:"Now"}`

You could also take a look at [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)